# time not shown in proper format ; extra unit

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Successfully calculated TotalTime a person has worked and overtime he has done if total working time is greater than 08:00 but if not greater than it puts duration of time person has not worked in Overtime column BUT NOW overtime column should display that time in  proper negative format e.g. if person has worked from 14:49 to
15:20 hours than Overtime column should show -00:29 but my column is displaying it like this 23:29, why 23: instead of 00: ? how can i get correct time ?

CODE

```
with times as (
SELECT    t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , min(t1.RecTime) AS InTime
        , max(t2.RecTime) AS [TimeOut]
        , cast(min(t1.RecTime) as datetime) AS InTimeSub
        , cast(max(t2.RecTime) as datetime) AS TimeOutSub
        , t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
FROM  AtdRecord t1 
INNER JOIN 
      AtdRecord t2 
ON    t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID 
AND   t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate
AND   t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
inner join 
      HrEmployee t3 
ON    t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID 
group by 
          t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , t1.RecDate
)
SELECT EmplID
,EmplName
,InTime
,[TimeOut]
,[DateVisited]
,convert(char(5),cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub as time), 108) totaltime
,convert(char(5), case when TimeOutSub - InTimeSub >= '08:01' then 
cast(TimeOutSub - dateadd(hour, 8, InTimeSub) as time) else cast(8 - (TimeOutSub - InTimeSub) as time) end, 108) as overtime
FROM times
```

Comment: It would be nice if you used some punctuation and politeness.

Comment: Sure sir, will try my best next time :) as u say :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the reason is because the Data type `TIME` is supposed to store time and `-00:29` is not a time (i.e. this time will never occur in a day).

What you are trying to do is show display duration in the usual format used to display time, this is not the same as showing time. This can be shown fairly simply by running:

```
SELECT CAST('-00:27' AS TIME)
```

Which throws the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The reason it is displaying this is because `00:00` minus `00:31` is `23:29` of the previous day.

I personally would do all the calculations using minutes, e.g.

```
SELECT  StartTime,
        EndTime,
        HoursWorked = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime) / 60.0,
        MinutesOver = 480 - DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime)
FROM    (VALUES 
            (CAST('06:50' AS TIME), CAST('15:20' AS TIME)),
            (CAST('07:50' AS TIME), CAST('15:20' AS TIME))
        ) t (StartTime, EndTime);
```

Which gives:

```
StartTime | EndTime  | HoursWorked | MinutesOver
----------+----------+-------------+------------
06:50:00  | 15:20:00 |     8.5     |    -30
07:50:00  | 15:20:00 |     7.5     |     30
```

You can then apply any formatting in your presentation layer.

---

[Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) does mention this in an article about [Choosing the wrong Data Type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type). It states:

**Using TIME to store duration**

> With SQL Server 2008, it may be tempting to store a duration in a column defined with the new TIME data type.  This data type is not meant to store duration but actually a point in time.  A problem with trying to store duration here is, what happens when your duration exceeds 24 hours?  It would be much more useful to store the "duration" in two columns - StartTime and EndTime.  You could add a third column which can be computed, calculating the duration in minutes or seconds or whatever makes sense.  Your choice for the StartTime and EndTime columns could be TIME if you are reasonably confident that durations will always be less than 24 hours and will not cross any midnight boundaries, but more likely they should be SMALLDATETIME or DATETIME.

---

**ADDENDUM**

The first thing I would do with your code is remove the inner join within the CTE:

```
FROM    AtdRecord t1 
        INNER JOIN AtdRecord t2 
            ON t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID 
            AND t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate
            AND t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
```

It is pointless, all it does is ensure that there is more than one record for each employee per day, which would be better achieved with a having clause. I would also [give your tables meaningful aliases](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3), with 2 tables is not really that necessary, but using t1, t2, t3 etc when you have lots of tables gets confusing quickly. So your query Becomes:

```
WITH Times AS
(   SELECT  emp.EmplID, 
            emp.EmplName,
            InTime = MIN(atd.RecTime),
            OutTime = MAX(atd.RecTime),
            TimeWorked = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(atd.RecTime), MAX(atd.RecTime)),
            OverTime = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(atd.RecTime), MAX(atd.RecTime)) - 480,
            [DateVisited] = atd.RecDate
    FROM    AtdRecord atd 
            INNER JOIN HrEmployee emp 
                ON atd.EmplID = emp.EmplID 
    GROUP BY emp.EmplID, emp.EmplName, atd.RecDate
    HAVING COUNT(atd.RecTime) > 1
)
SELECT  t.EmplID,
        t.EmplName,
        t.InTime,
        t.OutTime,
        t.DateVisited,
        t.TimeWorked,
        OverTime,
        FormattedTimeWorked = CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, t.TimeWorked, 0), 8),
        FormattedOverTime = CASE WHEN t.OverTime < 0 THEN '-' ELSE '' END +
                                CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, ABS(t.OverTime), 0), 8)
FROM    Times t;
```

**[Simplified Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fca74/1)**

Comment: great sir, amazing but could you edit my code to show whati want to display, i would append - sign as an charater but time ?

Comment: atleast there would be a way to show time a person has not worked, that would be helpful, i would append - sign later

Comment: You are my love sir, Amazing, Einstein you are :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you're subtracting Dates.

`January 14th, 14:49` - `January 14th, 15:20` is `January 13th, 23:29`. It makes sense if you think about it.

Use [SUBTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime) instead:

```
SELECT SUBTIME('14:49', '15:20'); -> '-00:31:00'
```

---

*EDIT:*

`SUBTIME()` isn't available in SQL-Server. My fault. But for anyone stumbling over this question it may be useful so I'll leave it here.

Comment: `SUBTIME` is a MySQL function. There is no equivalent in SQL Server.

Comment: @Evilrising To be a hairsplitter: Your question was "why 23: instead of 00:" and not "Could you please provide me the correct way to do this?" ;-)